# class are not add when clicking the 'a href'

Tags: jquery

```
function cat_skills(){

    //  if ($(this).hasClass("actives")){
        alert('hui');
         jQuery('.cateeg li categ.actives').removeClass('actives');
     jQuery(this).addClass('actives');
    //  }
        var  cat_skills= jQuery('.categ').prev('input[name="hidden"]').val();//jQuery('.actives').next().val();
        jQuery('.cat_ski').val(cat_skills);
        alert(cat_skills);
        var  cata= jQuery('.catt').val();
        var  cat_tags= jQuery('.cat_ta').val();
        var ajaxurl = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        var data = {
                'action' : 'fair_actionss',
                'cat' : cata,
                'cat_skills': cat_skills,
                'cat_tags': cat_tags
        };
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(data){
            //alert(data);
            jQuery('.custom_portfolio_file').html(data)

        });     

}
```

when i clicking to the a href tag the addClass and removeClass is not working but it showing an alert and also ajax function is working.

Comment: what is the context of this in that function ?

Comment: what is `this` in `jQuery(this).addClass('actives');`

Comment: you have to pass the event target element into that function.

Comment: echo '<ul class="cateeg">';
 foreach($clrterm as $term){ 
            $opt .= '<li class="fusion-filter  '.$term->slug.'"><a href="" class="categ" onclick="cat_skills()">'.$term->name.'</a><input type="hidden" value="'.$term->name.'" class="cat_skills"></li>';
 
 }
 echo $opt;
 echo '</ul>';

Comment: i mean from where you calling that function (cat_skills()) ?

Comment: call that function in footer

Answer (score 2):

When you are using jQuery, You should **bind** event handlers using it instead of ugly inline click handlers.

Your problem arise due in incorrect context of `this` and usage of incorrect selector `categ.actives` it will look for `categ` element with `actives` class

```
//Bind event using jQuery
$('.cateeg li a.categ').on('click', cat_skills);

function cat_skills() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("actives")) {
        //Your selector is incorrect
        jQuery('.cateeg li a.categ.actives').removeClass('actives');
        jQuery(this).addClass('actives');
    }

    //Your existing code    
}
```

---

Otherwise, pass the element reference which invoked the handler i.e. `this` to `cat_skills` function as

```
<a href="" class="categ" onclick="cat_skills(this)">
```

And modify your function as use the element reference

```
function cat_skills(elem) {
    if ($(elem).hasClass("actives")) {
        //Your selector is incorrect
        jQuery('.cateeg li a.categ.actives').removeClass('actives');
        jQuery(elem).addClass('actives');
    }

    //Your existing code    
}
```

Comment: i call that function in onclick event